# How do I correctly authenticate in mongo for a user that has access to multiple databases?

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I have a user with the role: `{role: 'root', db:'admin'}` which should have access to all the databases in my mongo instance. I'm using `mongoskin` in node.js to interact with mongo. My problem is that it isn't correctly accessing my databases. If I authenticate with

```
mongodb://owner:mylocalpassword@localhost:27017/mydatabase
```

It simply gives me `MongoError: Authentication failed`. If I instead auth with:

```
mongodb://owner:mylocalpassword@localhost:27017/admin
```

it authenticates, but I can't access `mydatabase`.

Here's my connection code:

```
var connection = mongoskin.db("mongodb://owner:mylocalpassword@localhost:27017/admin", {journal:true, auto_reconnect:true})
```

I assume that since I'm accessing the admin database there, that's the only one it interacts with. So I tried do then do this:

```
var mydatabaseConnection = connection.db('mydatabase')
```

But when I use that, my app is returning no results for queries on collections that I know have data. What am I doing wrong here? How do I get this user to access a database other than `admin`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so I found out that mongoskin's `db` method simply doesn't work. Finally I'm forced to completely remove mongoskin from my codebase. The real answer here is don't use mongoskin.

This code worked with mongo native:

```
MongoClient.connect("mongodb://owner:mylocalpassword@localhost:27017/admin", {journal: true, auto_reconnect:true}).then(function(db) {    
    console.log("Connected!")

    var mydb = db.db('mydatabase')

    var User = mydb.collection('User')
    return User.find({}).toArray().then(function(users) {
        console.log(users)
        db.close()        
    })
}).catch(function(e) {
    console.log(e.stack)
})
```